# Dynamically generated DocType in Elasticsearch DSL

Tags: python, elasticsearch, keyword-argument, setattr, elasticsearch-dsl

I am generating a `DocType` class for building mapping and saving documents based upon my ORM.

```
def get_doc_type(self):
    attributes = {}

    ...
    # Build attributes dictionary here

    DT = type('DocType', (DocType,), attributes)
    return DT
```

This seemingly works fine and I have no troubles with mapping. My problem is when I try to save documents.

**THIS DOES NOT WORK**

```
Doc = get_doc_type()

for instance in queryset:
    doc = Doc()
    for field_name in fields:
        attribute = getattr(instance, field_name, None)
        setattr(doc, field_name, attribute)
    doc.save(index)
```

When this happens, a document **does** get saved, however, none of my attributes are set. It is just an empty document.

I have debugged the code to confirm that the `field_name` and `attribute` contain the values I would expect.

**THIS DOES WORK**

```
Doc = self.get_doc_type()

for instance in queryset:
    kwargs = {}

    for field_name in fields:
        attribute = getattr(instance, field_name, None)
        kwargs.update({field_name: attribute})

    doc = Doc(**kwargs)
    doc.save(index=index)
```

When I use this strategy, the document is saved as expected, and all the information and `attributes` have been passed from my `instance` into the `doc`.

**QUESTION**

What could be causing this? It does not make sense to me why both strategies would not be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I guess, it must have some more info for the `save()` method to know which `field_name` should be stored.

Maybe like this:

```
    class Doc(object):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.fields_valid = kwargs.copy()
            ...
        ...
        def save(self, index=None):
            ...
            for field in self.fields_valid:
                do_save(field)
            ....
```

So you should look into both the `__init__` and `save` methods in the Doc class to find out what actually it does to persist the Doc object.

Answer (score 2):

I am having trouble replicate your behavior as everything works for me just fine:

```
class DT(DocType):
    pass

dt = DT()

for x in range(10):
    setattr(dt, 'i_%i' % x, x)
dt.save()

DT.search().execute()[0].to_dict()
```

Shows exactly what I would have expected. Could you please file an issue on github if it doesn't work for you as something is wrong in that case. Thank you!

Btw what I typically do when serializing from an ORM into `elaasticsearch-dsl` is to have a `to_search` or similar method directly on the `Model` that produces a `DocType` instance. It makes everything so much simpler, including synchronizing the both datasets using signals.

Comment: That's basically what I've done. I've made a model manager as a sub class of the django manager (which is where my method that generates the class is). I was trying to avoid having  to create a new class for each model, and instead just be able to add my mixin. When NOT  using `type` to generate a class, it does seem to work fine.